# Symbol for derivative in MAPLE

Tags: derivatives, maple, symbolic-computation

I am trying to use MAPLE to do some computations involving system of equations which terms are derivatives of functions.

When I type `diff(alpha(x),x)` it shows $\frac{d}{dx}\alpha(x)$. Is it possible to change this notation to obtain something like this: $\alpha'(x)$?

Comment: What is wrong with $\frac{d}{{dx}}\alpha (x)$?

Comment: Nothing wrong, theoretically. But since I have many symbols like that, not only for $\alpha$ (to be true I have $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$), it would be clear with prime notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change to $\alpha'(x)$, go to Preferences, Display and change Typesetting level to Extended (it should be Maple Standard by default). I have a Mac version, I believe it should be similar for PC. Another approach would be to type `interface(typesetting = extended)`. Use `interface(typesetting = standard)` to go back to Leibniz notation. Typing

`with(Typesetting):`
`RuleAssistant()`

should launch Typesetting Rule Assistant, which allows you to specify when to use prime notation and when to use dot (Newton) notation.

Comment: Hum, it does not work. I'm using Classical Worksheet. Maybe is this the reason? I'm using Linux.

Comment: Nice link, but I guess that my Maple's version does not have the option `prime` since that it isn't shown when I load the package `Typesetting`.

Comment: Typing `RuleAssistant()` should launch Typesetting Rule Assistant.

Comment: Thanks. This command opened the Assistant. I choose the option to prime notation but it does not work. I believe that I have some problem with fonts or java. I don't know. I am trying to open the non classical worksheet.

Comment: Before launching the Assistant type `interface(typesetting = extended)`. Type `interface(typesetting = extended)` again if it does not work the first time. I believe this should enable prime (Lagrange) notation.

Comment: No, nothing work. I tried the standard worksheet, opened the `RuleAssistant()` and marked the prime option, but nothing. I don't know. I have version 13.

Comment: Read my previous comment. Type `interface(typesetting = extended)`. Then try `diff(alpha(x),x)`. Use `interface(typesetting = standard)` to go back to Leibniz notation.

Comment: It works! So, in resume, I only have to use `interface(typesetting = extended)`. I closed and opened again and only with this single line I could change the notation. So, please, edit your answer and insert this command. Then I'll accept it.

Comment: The Typesetting Rule Assistant allows you to specify to which variables prime notation applies. If you type `diff(alpha(t),t)` and `diff(alpha(y),y)` you should get $\dot \alpha (t)$ and $\frac{d}{{dy}}\alpha (y)$, respectively. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: How can I keep prime notation when I convert the differential expression to latex format?